# What should the ohm, resistance, reading of a dishwasher thermostat be?

Tags: thermostat, dishwasher, resistance

The schematic doesn't say that I can see.  What should a "normal" resistance reading be for a dishwasher thermostat?  I do have continuity.  I read 1.3 or thereabouts.

It is a Kenmore, but Whirlpool part, WPW10195091.  High-Limit thermostat.  It was a room temperature when I took the reading.

The actual dishwasher is 665.14529N610.

I believe this is original manufacturer, but I can't see where it tells me a "normal" reading,

http://www.wako-clinac.co.jp/product_en/cs-7_en/index.html

CS-7SA

Comment: If you think there's the slightest chance that it might vary from model to model, manufacturer to manufacturer, it would be super handy for us to know the make/model of yours. Otherwise, we're guessing, just like you are.

Comment: You can't tell unless you are  holding the loose device in your hand.  The *other parts of the appliance and your house's electrical system* will interfere with in-circuit measurements, since they too are wired across the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resistance measurements vary. If you put your leads together it should read zero but most digital meters don’t have a zero function.

With this said I would be happy with 1.3 ohms  knowing the value may be much higher and still be good. What you want to make sure of when the thermostat is turned above the current temp set point of off the contacts open or read very high values.

Remember not to take resistance measurements on a live circuit most digital meters run on 3v or 9v for there ohm meters and getting hit with 120v can fry the meter.

If a live circuit I look for a voltage not resistance. with the contacts open possibly 120 or whatever the control voltage is and close to zero when the contacts closed.

I just looked at the link those are thermal snap switches, they will be all or nothing but when controlling line voltages 10-15 ohms will be fine as they age maybe close to 50ohms as the contacts get pitted and eroded.

Answer (score 1):

These devices are like switches:  when they are on, the resistance is close to zero.  When they are off, the resistance is close to infinite. They are actually a metal piece that bends as it heats, with contacts welded on it.